# Selenium + Apache POI+ Java

Tags: java, selenium, apache-poi

Im using below code to write data to a excel file in my local.

When i run the program it gives NullPointerException
Each time i run the scripts it has to append details to the next row.

```
Row header = sheet.createRow(4);
header.createCell(0).setCellValue("APPLICATION");
header.createCell(1).setCellValue("SITE");
header.createCell(2).setCellValue("TIME");
header.createCell(3).setCellValue("STATUS");

for (int i = 0; i < 9999; i++)
    HSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(i);

    if(row == null) {
        for (int j = 0; j <= 3; j++) {
             HSSFCell cell = row.getCell(j);
             if(cell == null) {
                  row.createCell(j).setCellValue(title);
                  row.createCell(j).setCellValue(url);
                  cellStyle.setDataFormat(  
                  createHelper.createDataFormat().getFormat("dd/mm/yyyy h:mm:ss"));
                  row.createCell(j).setCellValue(new Date());
                  cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
                  if(driver.getCurrentUrl().contains("https://www.google.com")) {
                     row.createCell(j).setCellValue("OK");
                     System.out.println("Page title contains- Google. Status is OK. ");
                  } else {
                     row.createCell(j).setCellValue("NOT OK");
                  }

                  System.out.println("Page title doesn't contain - Google. Status is NOT OK. ");
              }
         }
     }
}

Excel format: 
APPLICATION   SITE                 TIME                 STATUS
Google        https://google.com   02/09/2019 2:18:32   OK
```

Comment: Hi added code now, Plz check.

Comment: which line throws the exception?

Comment: if(cell == null) { ---- This line

Comment: if(cell == null)  can't throw a NullPointerException :)

Comment: `if(row == null) { for (int j = 0; j <= 3; j++) { HSSFCell cell = row.getCell(j);`: Here `row.getCell(j)` throws `NPE` because `row` is `null`.

Comment: HSSFCell cell = row.getCell(j); --- here :))

Comment: Can somebody help to fix this issue.

Comment: Well your code clearly tells that if `row` is `null`, then it shall try getting the `cell` at position `j` from that `row`. This cannot work because `row` is `null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try change this line

```
if(row == null) {
```

with this one:

```
if(row != null) {
```

As suggested by Axel Richter with the first implementation you enter in the if body only if the row is null, so when you try to access one of its members it throws a NullPointerException.

**For data problems**

executing this line

```
row.createCell(j)
```

a lot of time probably results in an on overwrite on the previously created cell with a loss of previous data.

Reading your code I can see that you are trying to set various values to the same Cell. I mean the same cell because with `row.createCell(j)` you are accessing the same cell all the time.

I think you should do something like this:

```
        if(cell == null) {
              Cell cell = row.createCell(j);

              if (j = 0) cell.setCellValue(title);
              if (j = 1) cell.setCellValue(url);
              if (j = 2) {
                   cellStyle.setDataFormat(createHelper.createDataFormat().getFormat("dd/mm/yyyy h:mm:ss"));
                   cell.setCellValue(new Date());
                   cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
              }
              if (j == 3) {  
                  if (driver.getCurrentUrl().contains("https://www.google.com")) {
                     cell.setCellValue("OK");
                     System.out.println("Page title contains- Google. Status is OK. ");
                  } else {
                      cell.setCellValue("NOT OK");
                      System.out.println("Page title doesn't contain - Google. Status is NOT OK. ");
                  }
              }
          }
```

Keep in mind that this is only an example: using 4 sequential if is a bad practice and you could (and really should) improve this code

Comment: Still it does not write data to the particular row/column.

Comment: my friend you have to be a bit more specific. you are asking for help, I will be happy to give it to you, but please do your job: give me as more descriptions as possible. Try to localize which of your lines are executed and let me know please, so I can try to understand what is happening on your pc :)

Comment: what problem do you have? no data at all or only some data? and so on

Comment: This my Excel format: 
APPLICATION SITE TIME STATUS
Google https://www.google.com/ 02/09/2019 17:33:28 OK
       
       
       
       

From Row 2 I have to insert the data for each time script is run. 
Likewise during each run, the script has to add row and column values as described without overwriting the existing data.

Comment: nup. not yet. Checking now. Hope i put my expectation clear :) Do let me know if otherwise.

Comment: Ur latest code prints same values in 3 rows... :(
What i expect is that for each run, the script has to append one row with defined column values. Each run = one row values (without overwriting the existing values)

Comment: I think you should set accordingly the values of title and url variables into the for loop. Otherwise they contain always the same valeus

Comment: would you help me do that please.

Comment: I can't. I don't know where you get these data

Comment: This is the code to get data from: 
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","chromedriver");
  WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
  driver.get("https://www.google.com");
  System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
  
  String title = driver.getTitle();
  String url = driver.getCurrentUrl();
  Date now = calendar.getTime();

Comment: I don't know Selenium, but you have to put these lines of code into the for loop. You have to achieve that for each row data are reassigned with new values. Obviously you need to set the proper url for each iteration, otherwise you will receive always the same data